# Project Server Console Application Error: The type name 'LoginWindows' does not exist in the type 'ProjectServer.WebSvcLoginWindows'

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to get rid of this error. I'm very new to C#, but please give any assistance you can. Thanks

Error: The type name 'LoginWindows' does not exist in the type 'ProjectServer.WebSvcLoginWindows'

Source Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using ProjectServer.LoginForms;
using ProjectServer.Statusing;
using ProjectServer;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using PSLibrary = Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library;
using System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectServer
{
    public partial class LogonProjectServer : Form
    {
        public static WebSvcLoginWindows.LoginWindows loginWindows =
            new WebSvcLoginWindows.LoginWindows();
        public static CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        public static WebSvcProject.LoginForms loginForms =
            new SyprisProjectServer.WebSvcProject.LoginForms();

        private const string LOGINFORMSWEBSERVICE = "/PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/LoginForms.asmx?wsdl";
        private const string LOGINWINDOWSWEBSERVICE = "/PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/LoginWindows.asmx?wsdl";
        private string baseUrl; // Example: http://ServerName/ProjectServer/

        public bool LogonPS(bool useWinLogon, string baseUrl, 
        string userName, string password)
    {
        const string LOGINWINDOWS = "PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/LoginWindows.asmx?wsdl";
        const string LOGINFORMS = "PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/LoginForms.asmx?wsdl";
        bool logonSucceeded = false;

        try
        {
            if (useWinLogon)
            {
                loginWindows.Url = baseUrl + LOGINWINDOWS;
                loginWindows.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                if (loginWindows.Login()) logonSucceeded = true;
            }
        }
        // Catch statements
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Logon Error", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Logon Error", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return logonSucceeded;
    }  
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to either the class name (LoginWindows) or the namespace (WebSvcLoginWindows) being incorrect when you create the loginWindows variable:

```
public static WebSvcLoginWindows.LoginWindows loginWindows = new WebSvcLoginWindows.LoginWindows();
```

Make sure the namespace and class name are spelled correctly and have the correct capitalisation.

If the class is contained in a separate asssembly, make sure your winforms project has a reference to the other assembly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build configuration and make sure all referenced projects are being built and being built for the correct configuration (64 vs 32 bit).  Also, ensure you are using the correct version of any referenced dlls.